# How to get phabricator to observer local git repository

Tags: git, phabricator

I'm running into an error when trying to observe a local git repository in phabricator.  The repo is on the same machine running phabricator and I believe has all the right permissions, but phab can't recognize the path.  Has anyone else run into a similar problem?  How have you resolved?  Thank you in advance for any guidance.

**The main error:**

```
phabricator-ssh-exec: Unrecognized repository path "/var/repos/git/test". Expected a path like "/diffusion/X/", "/diffusion/123/", or "/source/thaumaturgy".
```

**Steps I took to set up observed repository:**

```
Created a new repository in phabricator

Set the following (all) default URIs to "read only"
    ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/diffusion/1/test Read Only Hidden
    ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/source/test  Read Only Visible
    ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/diffusion/TEST/test  Read Only Hidden

Created a 4th URI and set it to observe:
    ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/var/repos/git/test Observe Hidden 

Set up credentials for that URI successfully

Activated respository
```

**The full phabricator error:**

```
Raw Error
Error updating working copy: Command failed with error #128!
COMMAND
git ls-remote '********'

STDOUT
( empty)

STDERR
Warning: Permanently added '[phabricator.localhost.com]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
phabricator-ssh-exec: Unrecognized repository path "/var/repos/git/test". Expected a path like "/diffusion/X/", "/diffusion/123/", or "/source/thaumaturgy".
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Short Summary:**

I tried using test.git too.  The directory /var/repos/git/test exists and is 775 (read, write, execute) by wdev group of which myuser and git are members

I can't figure out where phabricator is looking for these directories.  I expected from the root of my server, but /diffusion/X most defeinitely isn't at my servers root.  Am I making a wrong assumption?

I tried 3 other URIs all of which failed with same error.  I've provided more info below.

**tl;dr**

Additional steps resulting in same error:

```
1.  Changed URI to ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/var/repos/git/test.git
2.  Changed URI to ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/home/myuser/local-repos/git/test.git
3.  Changed URI to ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/home/myuser/local-repos/git/test
```

**My phabricator SSH user:**

```
[myuser@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/passwd |grep git
git:x:1002:1003::/var/repos/git:/bin/bash

[myuser@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/group |grep wdev
wdev:x:1001:myuser,apache,phd,git

[myuser@localhost ~]$ sudo cat /etc/shadow |grep git
git:NP:17669:0:99999:7:::

[myuser@localhost ~]$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/phabricator-sudoers
git All=(phd) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/ls, /usr/bin/git, /usr/bin/git-upload-pack, /usr/bin/git-receive-pack, /usr/bin/ssh
apache All=(phd) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git, /usr/bin/git-http-backend
myuser All=(phd) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /var/www/phabricator/phabricator/bin/phd
```

**Phabricator SSH user can ssh:**

```
[myuser@localhost ~]$ echo {} | ssh -p 2222  git@phabricator.localhost.com conduit conduit.ping
{"result":"localhost.localdomain","error_code":null,"error_info":null}
```

**Permissions on path to test repository**

```
[myuser@localhost apache2-php7-postgres]$ cd /var

[myuser@localhost var]$ ls -ltrh |grep repos
drwxrwxr-x.  3 myuser wdev   4.0K May  2 16:21 repos

[myuser@localhost var]$ cd repos

[myuser@localhost repos]$ ls -ltrh |grep git
drwxrwxr-x. 4 myuser wdev 4.0K May 18 08:00 git

[myuser@localhost repos]$ cd git

[myuser@localhost git]$ ls -ltrh
total 4.0K
drwxrwxr-x. 7 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:47 test

[myuser@localhost git]$ cd test

[myuser@localhost test]$ ls -alrh
total 40K
drwxrwxr-x. 4 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:47 refs
drwxrwxr-x. 7 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:47 objects
drwxrwxr-x. 2 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:47 info
drwxrwxr-x. 2 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:47 hooks
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myuser wdev   23 May  2 16:47 HEAD
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myuser wdev   73 May  2 16:47 description
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myuser wdev   66 May  2 16:47 config
drwxrwxr-x. 2 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:47 branches
drwxrwxr-x. 4 myuser wdev 4.0K May 18 08:00 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 7 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:47 .

[myuser@localhost test]$ pwd
/var/repos/git/test
```

**I then cloned test repository by running**

```
cd /home/myuser/local-repos/git/
git clone /var/repos/git/test
```

**I changed URI to use /home/myuser/local-repos/git/test**

**Directory permissions and contents of clone**

```
[myuser@localhost home]$ ls -ltrh |grep myuser
drwx------. 25 myuser myuser 4.0K May 18 08:10 myuser

[myuser@localhost home]$ cd myuser/

[myuser@localhost ~]$ ls -ltrh |grep local-repos
drwxrwxr-x. 3 myuser wdev     4.0K May  2 16:13 local-repos

[myuser@localhost ~]$ cd local-repos/

[myuser@localhost local-repos]$ ls -altrh
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x.  3 myuser wdev     4.0K May  2 16:13 .
drwxrwxr-x.  3 myuser wdev     4.0K May 18 08:00 git
drwx------. 25 myuser myuser 4.0K May 18 08:10 ..

[myuser@localhost local-repos]$ cd git

[myuser@localhost git]$ ls -altrh
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x. 3 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:13 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 3 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:47 test
drwxrwxr-x. 3 myuser wdev 4.0K May 18 08:00 .

[myuser@localhost git]$ cd test

[myuser@localhost test]$ ls -altrh
total 16K
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myuser wdev    3 May  2 16:47 init.txt
drwxrwxr-x. 3 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:47 .
drwxrwxr-x. 8 myuser wdev 4.0K May  2 16:47 .git
drwxrwxr-x. 3 myuser wdev 4.0K May 18 08:00 ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working for my set up.

I was using my phabricator ssh user (git) for this new ssh URI and turns out that user can't observer a repo that already exists on the local filesystem.  I changed the URI to use regular ssh on port 22 (not phabricator's ssh which is running on port 2222) and to ssh in as my user:

```
ssh://myuser@phabricator.localhost.com/var/repos/git/test Observe Hidden
```

So now I have the following URIs configured for this pre-existing local repo:

```
ssh://myuser@phabricator.localhost.com/var/repos/git/test Observe Hidden 
ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/diffusion/1/test Read Only Hidden
ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/source/test  Read Only Visible
ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/diffusion/TEST/test  Read Only Hidden
```

And Phab is observing my repository!

I don't know if this is standard, but for me, for my purposes right now, this works.  If anyone has other suggestions or ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 4th URL (yours), and change `ssh://git@phabricator.localhost.com:2222/source/test` to be in *Observe* mode. The error is caused by the fact that the URL should not point to the directory (in the filesystem) itself but to the URL(s) that Phabricator created to point to it.

Comment: I can't change any of the existing URIs (the default one's git creates) to observe mode.  But, I think I found the answer, I have to use my own user to observe this pre-exisitng repository.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You could also change the *origin* remote on your local repo to point to phabricator and then `git push`

Comment: XEB - is that a more standard set up?  I will try it either way to see what makes more sense.  I don't love using an individual's account to observe.